Is there any way to lock a process in java to prevent multiple instance at the same time after making an exe file with jpackage
I found this code here which basically allow only one instance of the app at one moment. The code works fine when I try to launch two instances af the jar file from the command line but after I use jpackage to make an .exe file I can launch more than one instances of the app at a time. Does anyone know why it behaves like this?
Is there anyway to  lock a process in java to prevent multiple instance of the same app at the same time after making an .exe file with jpackage?

That code in the example there may not be the best: If you start your same Java app from different directories (like cd-ing to different directories in a shell, then run java -jar /path/tp/app.jar), there will be multiple instances running, and process.lock files spread around those directories. The example given should use one global directory, not the app's current directory. The problem you encounter is probably that the .exe file extracts the (temporary) .jar file to randomly generated temp folders, all different, and each one one process.lock file in the process...

Use the registry (java.util.prefs.Preferences) to designate a global directory: 1) On start, check if that global key is defined 2) If not, find a directory (best is System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") or System.getenv("TEMP") or System.getenv("TMP")) and save the target directory to the registry. 3) Try to allocate the file process.lock inside that directory using the method given in the example, just with the absolute File: f = new File(tempDir, "process.lock");. This should do the trick and be safe to run on any system.

That title could use a rewrite.

Related: When are Java temporary files deleted?

I suggest that you copy the code from the link into your question because if that link dies, I'm not sure whether your question will remain useful after that link dies.

thanks everybody for the answers, I solved my problem with the answer given by the
JayC667. Thanks again JayC667

That code you found is an oversimplified version of what an application would need to do.  It’s more like notes on the concept than an actual solution.
The proper way to do this is to create a file in a known, stable location, not just in whatever happens to be the current working directory of the program.  There are a few different ways to let other attempts to open the program instead message the currently running instance.  One of the simplest is a local socket:
import static java.lang.System.Logger.Level;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class SingletonApplication {
    private static final System.Logger logger =
        System.getLogger(SingletonApplication.class.getName());

    private static final int MESSAGE_PORT = 25678;

    private static final Path PID_FILE = Path.of(
        System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),  
        SingletonApplication.class.getName() + ".lock");

    private final JFrame window;

    private void monitorMessages() {
        try (ServerSocket service = new ServerSocket(MESSAGE_PORT)) {
            Files.writeString(PID_FILE,
                String.valueOf(ProcessHandle.current().pid()));

            while (true) {
                try (Socket connection = service.accept();
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream(),
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

                    reader.readLine();
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> show());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Message service failed.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(PID_FILE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                    "Could not delete file \"" + PID_FILE + "\".", e);

            }
        }
    }

    public SingletonApplication() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(
            String.valueOf(ProcessHandle.current().pid()));
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(150, 150, 150, 150));

        window = new JFrame("Singleton Application");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(label);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private void show() {
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.toFront();
        window.requestFocus();
    }

    private static boolean messageExistingInstance() {
        if (Files.isReadable(PID_FILE)) {
            try (Socket messageChannel =
                    new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), MESSAGE_PORT);
                 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                        messageChannel.getOutputStream(),
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

                writer.write("start");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.log(Level.ERROR,
                    "Could not message existing instance.", e);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!messageExistingInstance())  {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                SingletonApplication application = new SingletonApplication();
                application.show();

                Thread monitorThread =
                    Thread.startVirtualThread(application::monitorMessages);
                Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
                    new Thread(monitorThread::interrupt));
            });
        }
    }
}

